# sql unique constraint

Tags: sql

What is the advantages of only one null for unique constraint is SQL Server?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? If it's a unique constraint you can't have null twice, obviously?

Comment: That may not be obvious, since one of the meanings of null is "unknown".  Does one unknown = another? Not in most uses of null in SQL! In other words (null = null) is false.

Comment: Yes, well then one could argue that SQL is wrong in it's enforcement of the unique constraint (and I would). Though I do happen to that that null = null being false is ridiculous. But my feelings on it won't change it :)

Comment: Technically (null = null) is NULL, which is interpreted as false.

Answer (score 1):

It is an advantage if you consider NULL to be a value that needs to be unique like other values, however most developers consider NULL to be the absence of a value and thus 2 NULLs are not equal and in this case this is a limitation that needs to be circumvented in SQL(unlike other DBMSs)

Comment: I wouldn't say 'most developers' consider that, I'd say 'SQL Server' thinks that. And personally I think it's a big, and very annoying, mistake. null is clearly null and null = null in my book. I have never ever need a value that says 'and make sure this never equals anything else'. But I digress. This is an argument worthy of it's on thread.

Comment: For me, this particular MSSQL 'feature' is usually a limitation so I have to work around it using one of the known methods, the view method is usually the cleanest.

Comment: I think filtered index is one of the best methods how to work it around. (MSSQL 2008 and later)